# jQuery droppable doesn't update element location while dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

So [Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yp70on2n/1/).

I have a table, then I put additional rows between those table rows to act as drop zones for reordering the table.  What's supposed to happen is that you drag the table row over the row beneath it, the drop zone below that row should be shown until you mouse over the original table row below that.  At that point, the old drop zone should be hidden and the new drop zone shown.  The result is a table that appears to be reordering while you drag.

Now the problem I'm having is that the droppable over function appears to fail to take into account the new row that's being shown.  It seems like it thinks the original table row is still in its old location. So what happens is when I drag the row over the row below it, the drop row shows up, then the instant I drag INTO that drop row, it thinks the third table row is there and it shows the next drop row.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("table tr").each(
        function () {
            $(this).after($("<tr></tr>").append($("<td>I'm empty space</td>").prop("colspan", 3).css("background-color", "cyan")).height(30).addClass("droppable").hide());
    })
    .draggable({
        axis: "y",
        helper: function (event, ui) {
            return $("<div>HEHEHE</div>");
        },
        stop:function(){ $(".droppable").hide(); }
    })
    .droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $(".droppable").hide();
            $(event.target).next("tr").show();
        },
        tolerance:"pointer"
    });

});
```

Comment: as your fiddle .. why you don't use sortable?? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/yp70on2n/3/ .. or you have more tables to drag and drop between them?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks! I ended up using that.  But that's more of a work-around than a fix.  It took a few hours to get that working when it felt like this issue should have been way easier.

Comment: yes it will take a time but you will get what you want .. but believe me if you trying to working around draggable and droppable you will keep trying hours and hours and you will get nothing .. Good Luck :)